# Create new column based on values from three other columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame('a'=c(1,NA,3,NA,NA), 'b'=c(NA,NA,NA,4,50), 'c'=c(NA,5,NA,NA,NA))
df
   a  b  c
1  1 NA NA
2 NA NA  5
3  3 NA NA
4 NA  4 NA
5 NA 50 NA
```

I need to create a new column d that combines only the values without the NAs:

```
  a  b  c  d
1  1 NA NA 1
2 NA NA  5 5
3  3 NA NA 3
4 NA  4 NA 4
5 NA 50 NA 50
```

Comment: `rowSums(df, na.rm=TRUE)`, or if it's always 1 and you don't want to risk summing it, perhaps `apply(df[1:3], 1, na.omit)` or `apply(df[1:3], 1, function(z) na.omit(z)[1])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Additional to the solution by @r2evans in the comment section:

We could use `coalesce` from `dplyr` package:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(d = coalesce(a, b, c))
```

```
   a  b  c  d
1  1 NA NA  1
2 NA NA  5  5
3  3 NA NA  3
4 NA  4 NA  4
5 NA 50 NA 50
```

*OR*

We could use `unite` from `tidyr` package with `na.rm` argument:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  unite(d, a:c, na.rm = TRUE, remove = FALSE)
```

```
   d  a  b  c
1  1  1 NA NA
2  5 NA NA  5
3  3  3 NA NA
4  4 NA  4 NA
5 50 NA 50 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do the following without using any libraries:

```
df$d <- apply(df, MARGIN=1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

```
   a  b  c  d
1  1 NA NA  1
2 NA NA  5  5
3  3 NA NA  3
4 NA  4 NA  4
5 NA 50 NA 50
```

It works as:
The function, `function(x) x[!is.na(x)]`, which takes a vector as input and return the non-na element from it, is applied to every row (margin=1).

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized option in `base R` is `max.col` to get the column index of non-NA, `cbind` with row sequence and extract the element

```
df$d <- df[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), max.col(!is.na(df)))]
```

-output

```
> df
   a  b  c  d
1  1 NA NA  1
2 NA NA  5  5
3  3 NA NA  3
4 NA  4 NA  4
5 NA 50 NA 50
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `fcoalesce` from `data.table`, which takes a dataframe and allows you to forgo having to add the column names.

```
library(data.table)

df$d <- fcoalesce(df)
```

**Output**

```
   a  b  c  d
1  1 NA NA  1
2 NA NA  5  5
3  3 NA NA  3
4 NA  4 NA  4
5 NA 50 NA 50
```

Or we could use `do.call` and `pmax`:

```
df$d <- do.call(pmax, c(df, list(na.rm=TRUE)))
```